# Kill nohup command on cluster

Tags: kill, nohup, cluster

Last night I launched a command via nohup on a cluster and then closed the connection. Today I would like to kill this job (I know it's still running because output is being generated in an output file) but I can't even determine its PID. If I type `ps -ax`, for instance, the name of my executable does not show up. Just typing `ps` only shows me executables that I have launched this login session.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I use `$ps -ef` all the time. For me it shows all process (even not owned by me) on linux hosts. Does it help for you ? Get the pid and kill it.

Comment: It depends on the OS. For BSD-derived systems, `ps -aux` is reasonably equal to `ps -ef` on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Try `jobs` command, if you can see it there take note of the job number and then `kill -9 %job_number_you_recorded`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lsof` to find the pid of what has that output file open.

Comment: lsof:command not found. Cluster is running Red Hat: Scientific Linux SL release 5.5 (Boron)

Comment: Run it as root.

Comment: I don't have root access on the cluster... Also, why would a command be recognized by root but not by another user?

Comment: Becaue on RHEL 5 and clones, `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` are not in normal users' `$PATH`. You can use the full path, but `lsof` works best as root.

Answer (score 0):

do you remeber the name of the process? Try to list with:

```
ps aux | grep -i $your_process_name
```

If you find that process you can easily kill it with ($pid = second column):

```
kill -9 $pid
```

You will not find that process in your current session, the `nohup` executed the given program then detached the program from your terminal. This parent-less process's parent will now be the init process (PID #1). You can see this with the command:

```
pstree -a
```

If you are sure, only one instance of given process is running you can easily kill with this:

```
killall -9 $process_name
```

for example:

```
killall -9 nano
```

Comment: `pgrep` is probably a [better tool](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) here than `killall`, since it can selectively search for the process name (with -f) and only select processes started by the user (-u)